# web3.eth.accounts[0] undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, accounts

I am new and I am trying to make my first transaction using geth and truffle.

to specify a sender address I type in the truffle console:

`src = web3.eth.accounts[0]`

but I get "undefined"

if I type `accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()`  it seems it works and I get an array with 10 accounts

but if I want only the first account of the list and I type `src = accounts[0]` I get again "undefined"

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: can you show your code? `web3.eth.getAccounts` is a method, so you need to call it like this `web3.eth.getAccounts()`

Comment: sory I forgot the parentesis, what I typed is: accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts(), I wrote it in the truffle console

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to do it this way.

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const src = accounts[0];
console.log("1st account: "+src);
```

I hope this works.

Edit: To provide more info.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('<your_ganache or geth address>'));
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const src = accounts[0];
console.log("1st account: "+src);
```

If using ganache-cli or geth, then your URL will be `http://localhost:8545` or if using ganache gui, it will be `http://localhost:7545` .

Everybody is new at some point. The community is with you.

Comment: I wrote the first line in the truffle console and I received an "undefined", but if I write: web3.eth.getAccounts() I receive a list of 10 addresses

Comment: yes you'll get 10 addresses because whatever local provider like geth or ganache you are using will generate 10 addresses by default

Comment: Now that will be in an array so you'll need to get the 1st element of that array

Comment: Also instead of calling the method in console, try writing a simple nodeJS file

Comment: if I write the three suggested lines in an "acccounts.js" file and I launch it with `node accounts.js` I get the error message "web3 is not defined".  sorry I am really new to this :(

Comment: Added more info into answer as to how your JS should look. See if that helps.

Comment: I followed your instruction, now I get the error message: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" p.s. thanks for the kind words

Comment: just remove await you should be fine

Comment: :( Now I get another error "const src = accounts[0]; TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Object.<anonymous>" many thanks for your patience

Comment: Try this. ```const Web3 = require('web3');


async function fn() {
const web3 = await new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
console.log('accounts: ', accounts);
const src = accounts[0];
console.log("1st account: "+src);
}

fn();
 ``` I think this should do it.

Comment: still not there yet, it seems the "accounts" variable remain undefined: `accounts:  undefined
(node:5446) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at fn ` could it have something to do with how I launched geth? I used `./build/bin/geth --ropsten --syncmode "fast" --datadir /home/xxx/Ethereum/Testnet/ --rpc --http --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" console`

Comment: Why don't you try using ganache-cli instead of geth. Install it using `npm install -g ganache-cli` and then run it using `ganache-cli -p 8545`

Comment: I installed and launched ganache-cli, I receive the same error message, the only effect is a line that appears in the terminal where ganache is running, where I find a `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545 eth_accounts`

Comment: I find it very weird because the same thing is working perfectly fine with me!

Comment: does it make any different from which path I launch the script? to launch it I have written the code with your suggestion in a file called accounts.js and I launched it via the command node accounts.js

Comment: I have that script on my desktop and it runs perfectly with `node acc.js` I mean acc.js is what I named it.